# Certain apps not showing up in app list after upgrade to Pie

Tags: google-pixel, app-drawer, 9.0-pie

I have a pixel 1 and I upgraded to Android Pie yesterday. Now I have started to notice missing apps in the app list. They are still installed and appear in widget form on the main screen but do not show up in the app list.

They all appear finance related which is also interesting.

Is there a new AI "feature" that filters rarely used apps from the list or something? Can I turn it off?

Comment: Did you figure out how to list all apps? So annoying!